# Ubuntu Openstack Installer stuck at dialog

Tags: openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I tried to install [Ubuntu Openstack Installer Kilo](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwi5kMPa_tPIAhWJWD4KHRoXCPY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.openstack.org%2Fkilo%2Finstall-guide%2Finstall%2Fapt%2Fcontent%2F&usg=AFQjCNGxHfzJRBwhxlk-zAmt_j6PhJcUKQ&sig2=soy_EyF3YwjcO7kqH-vA6w) with the command `sudo openstack-install`. But [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3JoP.png) happened.
Here are the Logs:

```
 [INFO: 10-21 11:01:05, openstack-install:200] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.23
[INFO: 10-21 11:01:05, openstack-install:201] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 10-21 11:01:05, openstack-install:212] Creating juju directories: /root/.cloud-install/juju
[INFO: 10-21 11:01:08, openstack-install:265] Running Kilo release
[ERROR: 10-21 11:01:08, ev.py:145] Exception in ev.run():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 143, in run
    self.loop.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 375, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1008, in run
    self._ioloop.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 646, in start
    event_pairs = self._impl.poll(poll_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 913, in poll
    callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 560, in entering_idle
    self.draw_screen()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 575, in draw_screen
    self.screen.draw_screen(self.screen_size, canvas)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 837, in draw_screen
    self.write(l)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 266, in write
    self._term_output_file.write(data)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-73: ordinal not in range(256)
[INFO: 10-21 11:01:08, utils.py:85] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Not currently, what are you using to run the installer (putty?)

Comment: Yes, I use PuTTY. I updated the post with some logs

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure PuTTY to use UTF8 as it's encoding.

Comment: Remote character set to UTF-8, still not working.

Comment: can you paste.ubuntu.com the latest ~/.cloud-install/commands.log?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12886651/

Comment: It still has the incorrect encoding, UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-47:.  I found http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2009/08/configuring-putty-to-use-utf-8.html which may help you set the right encoding with putty

Comment: @gangstaluv More elaboration of your answer would be nice. You should explain *how* to configure PuTTY, for example.

Comment: I don't own a windows machine to even begin to tell you how, i posted a link in the comments that should give you some indication.